# What were the mathematical techniques used for estimating euler number e upto 18 trillion trillion digits ??

Tags: exponential-function, approximation

While surfing, I came across this mathematical term: **$$(1+9^{-4^{6*7}})^{3^{2^{85}}}$$**
which approximately equals to the mathematical constant ***e*** (**Euler's number**) upto ***18 trillion trillion digits***.

What were the mathematical techniques used to approximate ***e*** upto 18 trillion trillion digits ?? What were the mathematical techniques used in finding the term **$(1+9^{-4^{6*7}})^{3^{2^{85}}}$**??

Comment: And uses all the non-zero digits once each in its formulation. Very flashy.

Comment: @Joffan Yeah, such numbers are known as **Pandigital numbers**. You can check more about them if you like. :')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1/x)^x = e$$

---

**Hint 2:**

> $$\frac{1}{9^{-4^{6*7}}} = 3^{2^{85}}$$

Also, watch [this video by Numberphile on the topic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgBGibfLD-U)

Comment: Appreciated., :')